# Tool for cleaning delicate crystal wine glasses

Tags: cleaning, kitchen

I have a very handy tool for cleaning Champagne flutes -- the long, slender glasses where it's very hard to reach the bottom of the glass. I think it's made by "Final Touch" but I suspect more than one company makes something similar.

Is there a similar tool adapted to wine glasses and water goblets? It's easier to reach inside those glasses, of course, but the tool still does a better job than, say, a sponge or a wet towel. It's hard to explain but the fabric of the device (it's some kind of terrycloth-like material) really gets anything off the surface of the crystal. I could use the flute tool, but I would prefer a tool that more closely matches the shape of the wine glass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a web search for a generic "soft tip [bottle/glass] cleaning brush" to see the variety available. The "soft tip" seems to be the feature you're looking for. The brushes come in a variety of shapes and with different kinds of "bumper" to cover the brush end to prevent scratching. Some use terrycloth you mention; but, most use a foam end. Some brushes come with a cloth bag for covering the plastic bristles when you put it into the container.

A second alternative that works well for glass is a micro-fibre cloth that you can use to wipe and polish your glassware after washing and drying.

I also have some high quality leather chamois "cloth" that works well and can't leave lint. You can find these at some hardware stores.

Good Luck.